# Matlab figure copy options in 2012b?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to save a copy of my figure without the white background.  Prior versions of matlab had various options to do with figure copying, such as the background color options and keeping screen resolution, etc.  Where did it go?  I found "figure copy template" in preferences, but none of that stuff is there.

Answer (score 0):

That option is still available in 2012b. From the figure, selected the `Edit` menu and `copy options.` There's a button for Transparent Background. This screen is also available from `copy figure template` by clicking the plus sign to the right.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this referenced before but I don't have it.  maybe linux vs. windows?  I'm on linux.

Comment: To be clear: I have "figure copy template", but there is no submenu for copy options.

Comment: This was on windows. I'm sorry, I can't help in that case!